# How to check whether a convex polyhedron is contained in another convex polyhedron?

Tags: convex-analysis, linear-programming, polyhedra, polytopes, discrete-geometry

Suppose we have two convex polyhedra

$$P_1=\{x\in \mathbb{R}^n \mid A_1 x \geq b_1 \}$$

$$P_2=\{x\in \mathbb{R}^n \mid A_2 x \geq b_2 \}$$

Is there a way to check whether $P_1 \subseteq P_2$? I was hoping that this can be done by solving some linear program. Is this possible?

Comment: If you want to show that $P_1 \subset P_2$, you have to show that $\forall \ x \in P_1 \colon A_2 x \geq b_2$

Comment: I wonder if you could do something with minkowski sums and minkowski portal refinement (MPR / Xenocollide) or GJK?

Comment: @aGer I'm trying to do that by coming up with a general method using something like Farkas lemma, but no success so far. :-(

Comment: What's interesting is that there is something called the *S-procedure* that does something every similar to this for *quadratic* forms. That suggests it *should* be possible for affine forms, but I'll be darned if I can figure out how.

Comment: What @aGer is proposing is possible, see [my answer to this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2097171/is-it-possible-to-check-polytope-containment-by-only-checking-the-feasibility-of/2097261?noredirect=1#comment4311892_2097261).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, here's one way to do it. Let $A_{i2}$ and $b_{i2}$ denote the $i$th row of $A_2$ and $i$th element of $b_2$, respectively. Then solve $m$ linear programs:
$$\begin{array}{ll}
\text{minimize} & A_{i2}^T x - b_{i2} \\
\text{subject to} & A_1 x \geq b_1
\end{array} \qquad i=1,2,\dots, m$$
If any of these have a negative objective, including possibly $-\infty$, then $P_1\not\subseteq P_2$. It's not cheap, I grant, but it works.

Comment: Would the problem be easier if, instead of writing $P_2=\{x \mid A_2 x =b_2, x \geq 0 \}$, I know $P_2$ is a cone with known extreme rays: $P_2= \{ R v \mid v \geq 0 \}$?

Comment: I don't think so, no. Unfortunately I don't think this is a convex problem. We are fortunate that it can be done this way.

Answer (score 2):

A not so elegant way would be to determine the vertices of $P_1$ and plug them into the constraints for $P_2$, if each vertex satisfies the $P_2$ constraints, then by convexity, so does the entire polyhedron.

As pointed out by @D.W., this approach will typically be very slow, as the number of vertices increases rapidly with the number of edges. Michael Grant's approach, as stated above and accepted, has faster running time.

Comment: That will work, except that finding the vertices given the faces is not straightforward.

Comment: Simplex doesn't attempt enumerate all the vertices, actually... indeed it would be quite bad if it did!

Comment: @Tony here's a paper to popular algorithm for vertex enumeration. This general problem is classified as NP-complete, so its not going to come cheap: http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF02293050

Comment: Unfortunately, the number of vertices of $P_1$ can be exponential in the size of $A_1,b_1$, so this procedure can potentially be extremely slow (exponential-time).  Therefore, this approach is not recommended if you need to solve the problem in practice.

Comment: @D.W. Wasn't this point already made in the above comments? I even pointed out that its NP-complete.

Comment: @Bey, well, if we must discuss the prior comments: no, vertex enumeration is not NP-complete.  It's not even a NP-problem.  NP is a class of decision problems; and NP-complete is a subset of NP.  Vertex enumeration is not a decision problem.  Moreover, vertex enumeration unconditionally takes exponential time; even if we discover P=NP, vertex enumeration will still take exponential time, as the number of vertices to enumerate can be exponential.  The best path forward would be to edit the answer to point out these limitations.  Shall I suggest an edit?

Comment: @D.W. I took a look at the paper I linked to and indeed they do not claim NP-completeness...that is my mistake. They do present an interesting algorithm that they claim can identify $v$ vertices in $d$ dimensions from $n$ non-degenerate inequalities in  $O(n^2dv)$ time. I can't verify that claim.

Comment: @D.W. I've already stated that the method is computationally expensive, however, I can edit to say that $V$ has the potential to grow exponentially with the number of inequalities to give a better sense of the difficulty. That seems like a good edit. However, exponential-time complexity is only one factor to consider...the simplex algorithm does not have a polynomial time guarantee...but usually it works rather well. Of course, my "algorithm" if it deserves such a name is brute force enumeration...this is why I said it was not an elegant solution.

Comment: @D.W. Finally (sorry, not trying to blast you or anything :-) .. you mentioned that this is not recommended in practice. Can you post an answer elaborating on this? If there's a more clever (general) approach out there for the poster's problem, I (and the poster and Michael Grant) would be really interested in seeing it. An automated, efficient method for verifying convexity for general sets of inequalities would be a great tool!

Comment: Posting an answer whose only message is to say "don't use that other answer because it will be slow" violates Stack Exchange rules, as that wouldn't be an answer to the original question.  The running time may be $O(n^2 d v)$ but the problem is that $v$ is (potentially/usually) exponential in $n,d$.  This is not the same situation as the simplex algorithm.  The simplex algorithm has the potential to have exponential running time in the worst case, but in practice it usually runs much faster than that (usually it visits only a tiny subset of the vertices).

Comment: Enumerating all vertices is guaranteed to require, well, visiting all vertices... unlike the simplex method.  In many/most real cases the number of vertices will be exponential, and in those cases, enumerating all vertices is guaranteed to perform poorly.  At risk of over-simplifying, think of it as the difference between "worst-case exponential in principle, but usually polynomial in practice" vs "always exponential".  Editing to say that the running time of this answer will often be exponential in the number of inequalities would be a useful edit.

Comment: The more efficient algorithm has already been posted by Michael Grant; its running time is guaranteed to be polynomial if you use the right LP solver, and will typically be efficient in practice.  I don't have anything better than that.

Comment: @D.W. Ah, got it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This is equivalent to the feasibility of the following linear constraints:
$$
\Lambda A_2 = A_1, \Lambda b_2 \ge b_1,
$$ 
where $\Lambda$ is a matrix with non-negative entries. The proof follows from the dual of linear programs that Michael mentioned.