# Is it possible to check polytope containment by only checking the feasibility of an LP?

Tags: algorithms, convex-optimization, linear-programming, computational-complexity, polytopes

**This is NOT a question about whether or not we can use LP to check polytope containment, which is already answered by existing posts on this website.**

Suppose we have two convex polytopes in their H-representatations

$P_1=\{x\in \mathbb{R}^n \mid A_1 x \leq b_1 \}$ and
$P_2=\{x\in \mathbb{R}^n \mid A_2 x \leq b_2 \}$

[The answer to a previous post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1344131/280478) requires solving a seriesof LPs, and then checking the non-negativity of the objectives, which is a two-step process.

I am wondering if there is a way to check whether $P_1 \subseteq P_2$ by only checking the **feasibility** of a single linear program (without rewriting $P_1$ into its V-representation)? If the answer is negative, is there an explanation using complexity theory?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The answer is affirmative. You want to verify $x \in P_2 \; \forall x \in P_1$. This is much like Robust Optimization, and the solution technique is the same. Let me write the constraints for $P_1$ as $Cx \leq d$ and for $P_2$ as $Ax \leq b$ for convenience. For each constraint in $P_2$, $(a^i)^T x \leq b_i$, we want to know if it is satisfied for all $x \in P_1$. This is equivalent to:
$$ \left[ \max_{x : Cx \leq d} (a^i)^T x \right]\leq b_i \quad \forall i$$
Take the dual:
$$ \left[ \min_{y^i \geq 0} \{ d^T y^i : C^T y^i = a^i \} \right]\leq b_i \quad \forall i$$
This inequality holds for the minimum iff it holds for at least one $y^i$:
$$ d^T y^i \leq b_i, \; y^i \geq 0, \; C^T y^i = a^i \quad \forall i$$
Now $P_1 \subseteq P_2$ iff this polyhedron is non-empty. Note that you can check emptiness for each $i$ separately, which is perfectly parallelizable.

Comment: Aha! Nice work.

Comment: @MichaelGrant Thanks. I guess I have to frame it now :)

Comment: Should you perhaps attach a comment to my other answer to point people to this? Obviously you commented on the question, but you didn't make it clear that this was a true alternative.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Nice method.

Comment: As a reference, unless I misunderstood the paper, the proposed solution corresponds to the Farka's lemma variant proposed in (Eaves & Freund, 1982 https://doi.org/10.1007/BF01583784). The mapping from this answer to the paper's notation is: for $P_1$: C,d → A,b, then for each facet of $P_2$: $a^i,b_i$ → c,d (only one outer inequality is considered in that paper), and for the dual variable: $y^i$ → λ.