# Is there a systematic approach of showing that a given set is contained in a given convex polytope?

Tags: reference-request, convex-analysis, polytopes

Let us assume that we are given a set $S=\{x\in \mathbb{R}^n:h(x)\le 0\}$, and we are given a set of points $p_1,\cdots,\ p_{n+1}$, such that $p_i\in S$. My question is:

> Is there a systematic way of checking whether the set $S$ belongs to the convex hull of the set of points $\{p_1,\cdots,\ p_{n+1}\}$?

I tried using contradictions, that is I assumed that there is a point $v\in S$, such that $v$ cannot be represented as a convex combination of the points $p_1,\cdots,p_{n+1}$, and tried to get a contradiction out of it by showing that $v$ will satisfy $h(v)>0$. However, the success of this approach seems to be highly dependent on the specific $h$ and the points $p_1,\cdots,\ p_{n+1}$. Can someone provide me with some reference to relevant literature where such cases are discussed and analyzed in some generality, i.e., results are derived for some general class of functions $h$?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should restrict at first your query to $S=$ sphere.

Comment: @JeanMarie, I guess that for the sphere the answer might be negative, i.e., I think that the convex polytope of any set of points that are within a sphere will not contain the sphere. However, please correct me if I am wrong. Anyway, my question was to seek for a general procedure when a particular $h$ is given. Is that even possible in general?

Comment: Sorry, I hadn't seen the $p_i \in S$...

Comment: @JeanMarie Its okay :-)

Comment: Because $p_k\in S$ by assumption, you surely get $conv(\{p_k\})\subset S$ provided $S$ was convex by itself.

Comment: @Dr.RichardKlitzing, I agree. However, I want to check whether $S\subset conv\{p_k\}$, which happens if the set is nonconvex, and is induced by the function $h$, which, whenever not convex, produces such nonconvex set $S$.

Comment: @samratmukhopadhyay. hmmm, you would get that $S\subseteq\ conv\{p_k\}$ only when you assume that those $p_k$ would be asked additionally to be extremal.

Comment: Why is this tagged convex-analysis? Is $h$ a convex function?

Comment: @LinAlg, I tagged this convex analysis because there is the convex polytope of the points $\{p_k\}$ involved.

Comment: If the convex hull of $S$ is a polytope (i.e., a bounded polyhedron), [checking set containment is easy](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2097171/is-it-possible-to-check-polytope-containment-by-only-checking-the-feasibility-of/2097261#2097261). If the convex hull is not a polytope, the answer is always negative.