# Finding containment between convex polytopes

Tags: algorithms, convex-optimization, linear-programming, computational-geometry, polytopes

Given 2 polytopes, either by their H-representations: $p_1: Ax\le b, p_2: Cx\le d$, where $b,d$ are real-valued vectors, $A,C$ are real-valued matrices, or by their V-representations: $p_1 = conv(p_{11}, p_{12}, ..., p_{1n}), p_2 = conv(p_{21}, p_{22}, ..., p_{2m})$, I want to find out if $p_1 \subseteq p_2$. What would be the best approach to go about it?
Currently, the best solution I've managed to come up with myself, is given V-representation, check if every vertex of $p_1$ is in the convex hull of $p_2$, and that takes $n$ linear programs.

I can decide if I want it the polytopes to be in V-representation or H-representation, but if the solution will take around the same running time - I'd rather it be in V-representation. If not, that's not a big deal.

I've found solutions such as [Is it possible to check polytope containment by only checking the feasibility of an LP?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2097171/is-it-possible-to-check-polytope-containment-by-only-checking-the-feasibility-of?newreg=f28ea4693adb42d2b051e441a5edd710) which claim to succeed doing so, while using only one linear program, given H-representation. I couldn't understand this solution though: I've tried proving it myself, but I can't understand some important things about it:

1. Why is it using equality in $C^Ty^i = a^i$, instead of $C^Ty^i \geq a^i$? Is it because according to strong duality, the solution to the maximization problem is equal to the solution of the minimization problem, if a solution exists?
2. How is it one linear program, if I need to check the existence of at least one $i$ which would give a none empty result? Isn't the amount of linear programs dependent on the amount of $i$s needed to be checked?
3. Why did they add the constraint of $y^i \geq 0$? I think I understand the intuition behind it, they wanted to make it a bounded problem, but doesn't it mess with the strong duality theorem, by adding another constraint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to solve it, if anyone comes across this and needs the solution:
Let $P_1$ be a polytope defined by the constraints $Cx≤d$, where $C$ is a $m_1×n$ real-valued matrix, $x$ is our real-valued variable vector, and $d$ is a $m_1$-dimensional real-valued column vector.

Let $P_2$ be a polytope defined by the constraints $Ax≤b$, where $A$ is a $m_2×n$ real-valued matrix, $x$ is our real-valued variable vector, and $b$ is a $m_2$-dimensional real-valued column vector.
We want to check if $P_1⊆P_2$.

$↔ ∀x∈P_1 (x∈P_2 )$

$↔ ∀x∈P_1 (∀_{1≤i≤m_2} (∑_{j=1}^{n}A_{ij}x_{j}≤b_{i} ))$ where $A_i$ is the $i$th row vector in $A$, and $b_{i}$ is the $i$th element in $b$.

$↔∀_{1≤i≤m_2} ([max⁡∑_{j=1}^{n}A_{ij}x_{j},s.t. ∀_{1≤k≤m_1}(∑_{j=1}^{n}C_{kj}x_{j}≤d_{k})]≤b_{i})$

Using the strong duality theorem, if the solution to the maximization problem exists, then it is equal to the solution of the dual problem. Hence, if the solution exists:

$↔∀_{1≤i≤m_2} ([min⁡∑_{k=1}^{m_1}d_{k}y_{k},s.t. ∀_{1≤j≤n}(∑_{a=1}^{n}C_{ak} y_{a}≥A_{ij})]≤b_i)$

This inequality holds for the minimum value $\iff$ there exists a value it holds for. Hence:

$↔∀_{1≤i≤m_2} (∃y(∀_{1≤j≤n} (∑_{a=1}^{n}C_{ak}y_{a}≥A_{ij}) ∧ ∑_{k=1}^{m_1}d_{k}y_{k}≤b_{i}))$

Now this problem can be solved via one large LP, where the solution vector of the problem will be of size $m_{2}n$, and every $n$ variables will represent one $i$ that we are checking. It's possible because we need to check if every $i$ has a feasible solution, and since for every $i$, the check needs to be done is independent from other $i$s, it's possible to either be done parallelly or in a single large LP.

Hope it can serve someone else well too :)

Answer (score 0):

Also managed to solve it in V-representation if anyone needs it:

Let $P_1$ be a polytope defined by his vertices $p_{11},p_{12},…,p_{1n}$.

Let $P_2$ be a polytope defined by his vertices $p_{21},p_{22},…,p_{2m}$.

We want to check if $P_1 \subseteq P_2$. Note, that due to convexity, $(\{p_{11}, p_{12}, ..., p_{1n}\} \subseteq P_2) \rightarrow P_1 \subseteq P_2$.
So, we'll check that instead:
$\forall_{v\in\{p_{11}, p_{12}, ..., p_{1n}\}}(\exists \alpha ((\sum^{m}_{j=1} \alpha_{j} = 1)\wedge(\forall_{1<=j<=m}(\alpha_j>=0))\wedge(\sum^{m}_{j=1}\alpha_jp_{2j}=v)))$

This is due the definition of a convex combination.

This can be done in a single LP, with $nm$ decision variables, where every $m$ variables will represent feasibility for a single vertex in $\{p_{11}, p_{12}, ..., p_{1n}\}$. We need to check that there exists $\alpha$ for every $v\in\{p_{11}, p_{12}, ..., p_{1n}\}$ independently, so it is able to be either done parallelly in $n$ different LPs, or a single large one.