# Efficient construction of the strict interior of a polytope.

Tags: linear-algebra, convex-analysis, computational-geometry, polytopes

Let $B_\infty(x, \delta)$ denote the set of all points within $\delta$ of $x$ in the $L_\infty$ norm.

For a vector in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and an index set $I \subseteq \{1, ..., n\}$ let $x_I$ denote the vector composed of those indices in $I$.

Given $A^{\textrm{eq}} \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$, $b^{\textrm{eq}} \in \mathbb{R}^{m}$, $A^{\textrm{ineq}}  \in \mathbb{R}^{p \times n}$, $b^{\textrm{ineq}} \in \mathbb{R}^{p}$, an index set $I$ (as above), and a $\delta > 0$ how can I efficiently (in less than exponential time) construct

$$
\left\{x \in \mathbb{R}^n : 
A^{\textrm{eq}} \zeta = b^{\textrm{eq}}, A^{\textrm{ineq}} \zeta \le b^{\textrm{ineq}}  \textrm{ for all } \zeta \textrm{ such that } \zeta_I \in B_\infty(x_I, \delta)
\right\}?
$$

If it is not possible to fully characterise this set, can I characterise a subset of it?

Stated geometrically, given a big polytope and some diameter $\delta$, how can I construct the set of points in that polytope for which it is possible to put a ball around some dimensions of that point that is also included in that polytope?

The method described in [this related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1343280/how-to-check-whether-a-convex-polyhedron-is-contained-in-another-convex-polyhedr)
 allows me to ask whether a point is in this set, and it works well. I'd now like to construct the set of *all* points.