# How to know whether a polyhedron fits within another?

Tags: geometry, elementary-set-theory, convex-optimization, convex-geometry, convex-hulls

I need to know whether a sofa fits within an elevator.

I know their dimensions, and I found this [topic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1343280/how-to-check-whether-a-convex-polyhedron-is-contained-in-another-convex-polyhedr).

However, does it check the fitting regardless of the orientation of the contained solid ? Or does it only try translating the moving object inside the container without changing its orientation ?

I know a bit about linear algebra but pretty much nothing about convex optimization.

Comment: In 3 dimensions, I assume. Correct?

Comment: Is your sofa convex? Or are you using its convex hull?

Comment: There are two different questions: does the sofa fits ? It is possible to enter the sofa in the lift ? The first is difficult. The second awful.

Answer (score 2):

This is a difficult problem in its full generality.
There is actually a paper entitled,
"On Moving a Sofa Around a Corner,"
discussed at [this MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/a/201692/6094).
See also [Sofa in a snaky 3D corridor](https://mathoverflow.net/q/246914/6094):

---

[image: SofaHammerslay]

          

<sup>Hammerslay's "sofa" in a corridor.</sup>

---